# MonoTouch.Dialog - freeze top row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Using MonoTouch.Dialog is it possible to freeze the first/top row (like a table header)?

Thanks!!
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several similar (but for Objective-C) questions for this on stackoverflow - you might want to read them as some might suggest alternatives better fitted to what you want to achieve.

Short summary: This is not how `UITableViewCell` works and not even how `UITableView` - i.e. both the header and footer views of a `UITableView[Cell]` will scroll. Since MonoTouch.Dialog is based on them it inherits the same *limitations* (which means `Element` and `Section` too).

The most common solution is to put a view before (header) or after (footer) the `UITableView`, e.g.

```
parent (UIView)
    header (UIView)
    table (UITableView)
    footer (UIView)
```

Note that this may not work (or require extra work) if you want to navigate with MonoTouch.Dialog and have only *some* tables showing an header.